# Inline CSS Styles Work, but External CSS Styles Don't

Tags: css, html, firefox, stylesheet

I need help.  This is ridiculous.

I'm using Komodo IDE, version 7.1.2, and Firefox version 15.0.1.

I created an HTML5 file like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>

<meta charset="utf-8" />

<title>Web Page</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="css/text" href="css/global.css" />

</head>

<body>

<div id="release">Release Date</div>

</body>

</html>
```

And the global stylesheet contains this and is located in a directory at the same level as the HTML file called `css`:

```
#release {
    text-align: center;
    font: small-caps;
    border-top: solid 1px;
    border-bottom: solid 1px;
    border-right: solid 10px;
}
```

Here is a picture of the directory structure:

[image]

I put the same styling into he HTML file and it works, but the styling isn't working with the external stylesheet.  I am not new to website development, so this is particularly puzzling to me.

I tried this same thing on two Windows 7 machines and one Ubuntu 11.10 machine as well, with the same anomaly.

Here is the fiddle working:

http://jsfiddle.net/NKq8N/1/

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `<link>` attribute, the `type` should be "text/css", not "css/text".

Comment: Dude!  Thanks.  Sometimes it's just the stupid little things.  I think I was hornswaggled because my IDE auto-filled it for me.  I should look into that.

Comment: So the next question is why does jsfiddle.net accept this but not browsers?  Just curious.  I mean, other than it being incorrect ;--)

Comment: Because to jsFiddle, the stuff you put in the "CSS" tab is read as if it were inline. You don't need to define a `<link>` in the jsFiddle because the CSS tab is automatically connected to the page. Same thing with the JavaScript tab, all the code in that part is read as an inline `<script>` tag. You can even inspect the HTML in that frame, it will show your code in an inline `<style>` tag.